# Differences between maven archetype commands and maven command mvn package?

Tags: maven

Could somebody tells me, what are the differences between the command mvn archetype:generate and the commands mvn clean package or mvn clean install.

Thanks a lot!
Maik

Answer (score 2):

- `archetype:generate` generates a brand new project from a template
- `clean package` clean and package the project
- `clean install` clean, package the project and install it into the local repo. (i.e. `~/.m2/repository`)

For more info, see [the documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/)